# How to sticky bottom when there's not enough content to overflow?

Tags: html, css

When there's enough content to overflow, everything works perfectly. Take a [look here](https://jsbin.com/wofolisuni/edit?html,output).

However, when there isn't, I still want the red `<sticky-guy>` element to stick to the bottom of the `<scroller>` element. The `<scroller>` is supposed to represent a device's screen, ergo, the `overflow: auto` property.

Here's a demo without enough content to overflow: https://jsbin.com/jigoxekeje/1/edit?html,output

Important to note: All heights here are to be taken as dynamic. The `<scroller>` box is the width/height of the window, whereas the heights of the `<head-content>`, `<body-content>`, and `<sticky-guy>` depend on their content size.

```css
scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
head-content {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
body-content {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
sticky-guy {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<scroller>
    <head-content>
      head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content 
    </head-content>
    <body-content>
        body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content 
        <sticky-guy>
          sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky 
        </sticky-guy>
    </body-content>
</scroller>
```

Comment: what about `display:contents` to body-content?

Comment: @TemaniAfif just tried it, didn't work. `<sticky-guy>` stayed in place.

Comment: it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/pok37zrs/ unless you are using a browser that doesn't support display:contents

Comment: @TemaniAfif here's [what I see](https://imgur.com/a/WkAtbMg) in Chrome. The `<sticky-guy>` doesn't drop to the bottom of `<scroller>`.

Comment: you need this https://jsfiddle.net/pok37zrs/2/ then? you are using sticky the wrong way I guess

Comment: @TemaniAfif no sir : ) I don't consider that a sticky behavior. I need `<sticky-guy>` over the `<body-content>` while `<body-content>` is visible. What I've provided in the example actually works perfectly when the content is large enough to overflow the `<scroller>`. The problem starts when there isn't enough content to overflow it. Take a [look here](https://jsbin.com/jigoxekeje/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: did you check my last snippet? you need the div to always be at the bottom of element (this is what I did there)

Comment: @TemaniAfif [here's what](https://imgur.com/rTs0Udu) I get from it when I add some more content. There is no sticky behavior there.

Comment: because I removed the sticky property since I wasn't sure what you meant by *sticky*. Add it again to my last snippet and it will work ... By the way, I see that someone made an answer using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `body-content` a flex element, you will be able to send `sticky-guy` to the bottom of it when the content is not overflowing.

Add those rules to `body-content`:

```
  display: flex; /* instead of display: block; */
  flex-direction: column;
```

And this rule to `sticky-guy`:

```
  margin-top: auto;
```

In the snippet, I used a height of 100vh for the `scroller`, so that you can easily see that it works with the content overflowing or not.

(it's actually almost the same answer as @Temani Afif did. You just needed to keep the sticky rules for `sticky-guy`)

```css
scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

head-content {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

body-content {
  /*********** Added rules */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*********** */
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

sticky-guy {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  /*********** Added rule */
  margin-top: auto;
  /***********  */
}
```

```html
<scroller>
  <head-content>
    head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content
  </head-content>
  <body-content>
    body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content
    <sticky-guy>
      sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky
    </sticky-guy>
  </body-content>
</scroller>
```

EDIT

It works with Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari.
It seems like Safari interprets flex differently. Using `flex: 1` on `body-content` will limit its height to the `scroller` container's height.
That's why it "loses" its background color. In fact, [body content body ...] is overflowing `body-content`.
I don't see a 100% clean solution yet.

What you could do of course is put `scroller`'s backround-color in yellow as well.

```css
scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  /*********** Added rules */
  background: yellow;
  /*********** */
}

head-content {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

body-content {
  /*********** Added rules */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*********** */
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

sticky-guy {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  /*********** Added rule */
  margin-top: auto;
  /***********  */
}
```

```html
<scroller>
  <head-content>
    head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content
  </head-content>
  <body-content>
    body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body
    content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body
    content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content
    <sticky-guy>
      sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky
    </sticky-guy>
  </body-content>
</scroller>
```

And finally with a clean fix for Safari.

Add this rule to `body-content`:

```
min-height: fit-content;
```

```css
scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

head-content {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

body-content {
  /*********** Added rules */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: fit-content; /* For Safari */
  /*********** */
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

sticky-guy {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  /*********** Added rule */
  margin-top: auto;
  /***********  */
}
```

```html
<scroller>
  <head-content>
    head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content head content
  </head-content>
  <body-content>
    body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body
    content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body
    content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content body content
    <sticky-guy>
      sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky sticky
    </sticky-guy>
  </body-content>
</scroller>
```

Comment: Great! That seems to be it. Gotta ask tho, when I add back the extra content in [your solution](https://jsbin.com/reresarowa/1/edit?html,output), the `body-content` loses it's background color. Why? What other side-effects are there?

Comment: True... It works with Firefox but not with Safari. I'll investigate.

Comment: I edited my answer. Safari is interpreting flex differently than other browsers, but don't know how to make a 100% clean solution yet. Anyone?